# Built in webcam disappeared while running C# webcam program

Tags: c#, webcam

I was running this Visual Studio project, that has been working for over two months:
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/125478/Versatile-WebCam-C-library

Today, I clicked on the 'Start' button, and the program froze. I force quit it, but since then, my built in webcam has disappeared completely.

In the device manager an 'Unknown device' showed up which I uninstalled, but haven't found a webcam driver to my laptop (Acer Aspire F5-573G).

I also have an Ubuntu on my computer, but it's also unable to find my webcam.

Any help is deeply appreciated.

Comment: Try removing the unknown device in safe mode.  If that doesn't work, find the .inf file and remove that too to force a new one to be downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by downloading a webcam driver form Realtek which ended up working.